# Reduced data usage when using YouTube in background?

Tags: ios, youtube

As I understand it, it's possible to listen to YouTube audio in the background, by playing it from the safari app, on iOS devices. What I wonder: does doing this reduce the bandwidth, the amount of data because solely audio (and no video) is being output?

Answer (score 4):

No, even though you're only listening to the audio, the video will continue to be streamed to the device.